# How does Sandcastle Conceptual Help compare to Doxygen Pages?

Tags: doxygen, sandcastle

Sandcastle has a fairly complex XML [MAML](http://docproject.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Sandcastle%20Help&referringTitle=How%20To%20Use%20the%20Topic%20Management%20Dialog&ANCHOR#MAML) for generating [Conceptual Help](http://docproject.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Sandcastle%20Help&referringTitle=How%20To%20Use%20the%20Topic%20Management%20Dialog&ANCHOR#MAML), as discussed in a [nice intro from 2007](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/winhelp/SandcastleConceptual.aspx). How does this compare to Doxygen in terms of ease of writing content and control over generation of the pages?

I am a big fan of using the Doxygen [page](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdpage) facility to write such conceptual help including discussions of design issues. It is much less structured - there's the [main page](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdmainpage) and you can then choose how you group pages by adding links with [subpage](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdsubpage) or [ref](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdref) commands.

I also like the fact I can include casual Graphviz diagrams in my doxygen pages either with inline fragments or referring to an external file.